# fixed height div with overflow causes wrapping of content

Tags: css

I have a list of bullets inside a div with a fixed height. Width is dynamic, determined by the content of the div, which in this case is a bullet list.  The overflow is set to auto, so when a longer list is used, it adds a scrollbar to the div.

The issue is that when it adds the scrollbar, the list items no longer fit the same, and it causes the longer one(s) to wrap, where they would normally sit hard into the right margin.

Example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6uguL/

```
#wrap {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

<div id="wrap">
<ul>
    <li>short list item 1</li>
    <li>short list item 2</li>
    <li>short list item 3</li>
    <li>this list item longer</li>
    <li>short list item</li>
    <li>short list item</li>
    <li>short list item</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

If you change the height of the div to 250px the list sits nicely, one per line, no wrapping, but set the height to 150px and the long line now wraps because of the scrollbar being added.

Is there a way to account for the potential existence of the scrollbar and add padding/margin/whatever to stop any unnecessary wrapping occurring?

Note that white-space:nowrap is not an option and the div should only be as wide as it needs, based on the content, but still allow wrapping for very long lines if needed (in case some lines are very, very long)

Comment: Add white-space: nowrap; to your #wrap rule. This will force the text on the same line.  However, the text might be obscured by the scrollbar so like @jenova70 suggests, you probably will have to add padding-right.

Comment: can't use nowrap as some lines may have to wrap if they are longer than the screen/space is wide. I just want the div to get fatter when it adds the scrollbar rather than compress the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I have some possibilities, but they all have a downside, so I guess some people will find better answers :

- You can ad `overflow-y:scroll;` to the division. The scroll-bar will always be here, but just greyed out
- Ad some `padding-right` to compensate the room taken by the scroll-bar
- I think this one is the best solution : Download [perfect-scrollbar](http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/). It is a `jQuery` plugin that do not affect the original design layout. If you can use `JavaScript` and `jQuery`, that's the best solution I have

Comment: sadly, the scrollbar doesn't seem to take the space provided by the padding/margin. And not so keen on permanent scrollbars :(

Comment: So what about perfect-scrollbar ? It is really little configuration